# JQuery.Validate failure in Opera

Tags: jquery, validation, opera

If you're using Opera 9.5x you may notice that our client-side [JQuery.Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) code is disabled here at Stack Overflow.

```
function initValidation() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1) return;
    $("#post-text").rules("add", { required: true, minlength: 5 });
}
```

That's because it generates an exception in Opera! Of course it works in every other browser we've tried. I'm starting to seriously, seriously hate Opera.

This is kind of a bummer because without proper client-side validation some of our requests will fail. We haven't had time to put in complete server-side messaging when data is incomplete, so **you may see the YSOD on Opera much more than other browsers**, if you forget to fill out all the fields on the form.

Any Opera-ites want to uncomment those lines (they're on core Ask & Answer pages like this one -- just View Source and search for `"Opera"`) and give it a go?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

turns out the problem was in the

```
{ debug : true }
```

option for the JQuery.Validate initializer. **With this removed, things work fine in Opera.** Thanks to Jörn Zaefferer for helping us figure this out!

Oh, and the $50 will be donated to the JQuery project. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce this bug. Can you give more details?

I have my copy of Opera masquerading as Firefox so the validation should be executing:

```
>>> $.browser.opera 
false
```

When I go to the edit profile page and enter a malformed date, the red text comes up and says "Please enter a valid date". That's jQuery.Validate working, right? Does it only fail on certain forms/fields?

This is Opera 9.51 on WinXP.

Edit: testing editing on Opera.

Edit: It also works when I comment out the "if ($.browser.opera) return;" line on a copy of the edit profile page I saved locally. I really can't reproduce this bug. What is your environment like? (Vista? Opera plugins?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not up on .NET but I'm guessing YSOD implies uncaught errors, if that's the case then isn't relying on client-side validation alone a little risky? If not then errors that are caught can be converted to something useful for the Opera crowd - even if it is just a Screen Of Death painted white with validation grumbles ...